# Egg free steamed raspberry pudding

Tags: raspberries, steamed-pudding

This is an old recipe. Back in the 1940s to the 1970s, my mom used to make individual raspberry puddings steamed in her handleless cups. I can't recreate it.

I think it had baking soda and/or baking powder in it. I don't think it had eggs. It was somewhat grayish in color It did not have a golden top or texture and taste akin to a sponge pudding as is true with every raspberry steamed pudding I've seen or tried. I remember it had a slight baking powder/soda taste.

Has anyone had this and knows how to make it? My 80-year-old brother and I would love to make it. My budget is nearing its end for buying fresh raspberries in January.

Comment: Welcome Germaine! Can you share recipes that you have tried so far, and what isn't working about them? Unfortunately requesting a recipe for a dish is not on-topic (there might be multiple ways of doing it) but we can help refine what you have.

Comment: There are people who are going to try closing this as a ‘recipe’ request unless you specifically mention what you’ve tried and how it didn’t quite come out like you expected.  But to try to actually help you with your actual question.... where did you grow up, and where was your mother’s family from?  Did you mother tend to stick to old family recipes, exchange recipes with friends, or try new things from magazines?  Did she ever mention anything about the history of it?  (Like her mom used to make it for her, or or she loved it growing up, etc)

Comment: Hmm, non-golden top would imply that it was cooked in an improperly sealed steamer with a lid on - water drips onto the surface causing discolouration/pale colour. Also was it jam or fresh raspberries, most recipes I know for this use jam.